# Python built JSON with mixed types

Tags: python, json

Actually I build Json object starting from a python object.

My starting JSON is:

```
    responseMsgObject = {'Version': 1,
                         'Id': 'xc23',
                         'Local': "US"
                         'Type': "Test",
                         'Message' : "Message body" }

    responseMsgJson = json.dumps(responseMsgObject, sort_keys=False )
```

Every things works but now I need to put the JSON below into "Message" field.

```
  {
  "DepID": "001",
  "Assets": [
    {
      "Type": "xyz",
      "Text": [
        "abc",
        "def"
      ],
      "Metadata": {
        "V": "1",
        "Req": true,
        "Other": "othervalue"
      },
      "Check": "refdw321"
    },
    {
      "Type": "jkl",
      "Text": [
        "ghi"
      ],
      "Metadata": {
        "V": "6"
      },
      "Check": "345ghsdan"
    }
  ]
}
```

I built many other json (but simpler) but I'm in trouble with this json.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: Please edit the question to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including specifically the part you are struggling with and the associated stack trace (if any).

Comment: I update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to replace true with True works fine for me

```
import json
responseMsgObject = {
    'Version': 1,
    'Id': 'xc23',
    'Local': "US",
    'Type': "Test",
    'Message': {
        "DepID": "001",
        "Assets": [{
            "Type": "xyz",
            "Text": [
                "abc",
                "def"
            ],
            "Metadata": {
                "V": "1",
                "Req": True,
                "Other": "othervalue"
            },
            "Check": "refdw321"
        }, {
            "Type": "jkl",
            "Text": [
                "ghi"
            ],
            "Metadata": {
                "V": "6"
            },
            "Check": "345ghsdan4"
        }]
    }
}

responseMsgJson = json.dumps(responseMsgObject, sort_keys=False )
print("responseMsgJson", responseMsgJson)
```

[DEMO](http://pythonfiddle.com/json-test-456)

Comment: I need to put this json inside another json. Specifically into the "Message" field

Comment: I replace Message body in first json with second json is it correct ?

Comment: { 'Version': 1,'Id': 'xc23', 'Local': "US", 'Type': "Test", 'Message' : HERE THE SECOND JSON }

Comment: Sorry I haven't read deeply. Basically Can I create a python object with array and moch more inside? And then convert to JSON?

Comment: I this yes you can if value can convert to string